# Ruby Watir syntax for setting a text_field with no id and odd parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby, watir

I'm trying to set a text_field and text area on a webpage that doesn't have an id any longer.  I'm guessing the site is trying to avoid automation.    The input and textarea tags are inside of a form.  Here are the input and textarea tags and what is contained.

```
<input class="uniform-input ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-maxlength" type="text" data-invalid-chars="" data-max-length="50" required="" placeholder="Subject" data-float-label="true" data-ng-model="message.Subject"></input>

<textarea class="uniform-input ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-maxlength" data-invalid-chars="" data-max-length="4000" required="" placeholder="Enter your message here" data-ng-keypress="view.error = false" data-float-label="true" data-ng-model="message.Body"></textarea>
```

Also there is a button that I need to click after submitting the text with this button tag:

```
<button data-ng-if="!paymentInfo" type="button" class="button button-grey ng-scope" data-ng-click="ctrl.sendMessage()" data-ng-disabled="view.waiting" data-ng-class="{ 'button-disabled': view.waiting }">Send Now</button>
```

How do I click it when it has no name?

Any help as to how to set this with Watir would be very appreciated.  If Watir is unable to do it is there a possible JS workaround that I could use?  Please let me know if any further information is needed to help.

Comment: If you want to populate all the text inputs on the page, you could use `browser.text_fields.each { |el| el.set "str"}`.  Or you could target the text input based on class and index.  For example: `b.text_field(:index => 0, :class => "uniform-input ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-maxlength").set "str"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using ruby gem watir

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
$browser = Watir::Browser.new
$browser.goto "yourwebsite.com"

$x = 0
def test
  print "#{$x}"
  begin
   $browser.text_fields[$x].set "#{$x}"
  rescue StandardError => e
   puts " no text field found, try again.\n\n"      
  end
  $x += 1
end
```

Keep changing the value of X to see what text fields you are manipulating. I suppose you could make a loop but you might get an error. Keep calling test until you find what you're looking for.

Comment: That works great, but I've run into another issue, there is a button after these fields that I need to click with this html:        <button data-ng-if="!paymentInfo" type="button" class="button button-grey ng-scope" data-ng-click="ctrl.sendMessage()" data-ng-disabled="view.waiting" data-ng-class="{ 'button-disabled': view.waiting }">Send Now</button>

Comment: $browser.buttons[x].click #change x with the correct number of buttons. also works with $browser.links[x].click

Comment: Thanks for the great anwer...The buttons doesn't seem to be working though.  Is there any way to output each of the buttons...I used a simple for loop and nothing is happening...browser.buttons[i].click doesn't do anything.

Comment: I would like to help you but I would need to see the website you're trying to automate. I'll be shooting blind in the dark. You can try using .css.. $browser.element(:css => 'button[@class="button button-grey ng-scope"]').click

Comment: Thanks for the help...everything seems to be cruising along now.

Answer (score 0):

The elements do look like they have some descriptive attributes. The text fields have a `data-ng-model` that describes the field. As well, the button has a text that is likely unique.

Therefore, I would do:

```
browser.text_field(:data_ng_model => 'message.Subject').set('subject text')
browser.textarea(:data_ng_model => 'message.Body').set('body text')
browser.button(:text => 'Send Now').click
```

I think this approach is more expressive in terms of what your code is doing. As well, it can be more robust as it is not susceptible to fields being re-ordered or other fields being added/removed.

Answer (score 0):

I have been identifying those ng-data objects via xpath, mainly when there is not a more specific way to identify them. Justin is right about an approach that is robust; find a way taht does not need to be refactored down the road. Here is what I would have:

```
browser.text_field(xpath: '//input[@data-ng-model="message.Subject"]').set("Hello")
browser.button(:text => 'Send Now').click
```

I prefer not using a lot of xpath, except for when it guarantees me a unique way to find an object on a page.